# How to sort by subscript

Tags: list-manipulation, sorting

I notice that

```
In[1]:= Sort[{Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 5], Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 4]}]

Out[1]= {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3],Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]}
```

But

```
In[2]:= Sort[{Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[d, 5], Subscript[e, 1], Subscript[b, 4]}]

Out[2]= {Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[b, 4], Subscript[c, 2],Subscript[d, 5], Subscript[e, 1]}
```

How can I use SortBy to sort by subscript only?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try with:

```
SortBy[{Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[d, 5], Subscript[e, 1], Subscript[b, 4]}, #[[2]] &]
```

> {Subscript[e, 1], Subscript[c, 2], Subscript[a, 3], Subscript[b, 4],
>   Subscript[d, 5]}

```
SortBy[{Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 5], Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 4]}, #[[2]] &]
```

> {Subscript[x, 1], Subscript[x, 2], Subscript[x, 3], Subscript[x, 4], Subscript[x, 5]}

Comment: One can also replace `#[[2]] &` by `Last`.